Geoserver configuration
i hope that you are feeling well.
i am writing to ask for hellp
First i want to tell you what it happened,
i installed geoserver on my VPS was easly and it work,
but the problem is, when i publish my layer and
i try to conect geoserver with my leaflet  using ajax but when i open map in my browser the layer is not showed
i did all thing in geoserver like active wmf
below see the photo of configuration and my js code


$.ajax('http://data.guivalamap.com:8080/geoserver/ows',{
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    service: 'WFS',
    version: '1.1.0',
    request: 'GetFeature',
    typename: 'ba:resultado2',
   
    srsname: 'EPSG:4326',
    outputFormat: 'text/javascript',
    },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback:'callback:handleJson2',
  jsonp:'format_options'
 });
  //Geojson style file
  
  var myStyle = {
    "color": "#ff9800",
    "weight": 5,
    "opacity": 0.65
   };
   
 
// the ajax callback function

function handleJson2(data2) {
    selectedArea2 = L.geoJson(data2, {
      style: myStyle,
      onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.conta);
        layer.bindPopup(`Name da Comunidade: ${feature.properties.conta}`)
        
        layer.on({
          mouseover: function(e) {
              e.target.setStyle({
                fillColor:'#ff7f00',
                  dashArray: '',
                  weight: 2,
                  opacity: 1
              });
              if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
                  e.target.bringToFront();
              }
          },
          mouseout: function(e) {
              geojsonLayer.resetStyle(e.target);
          },
          click: function(e) {
              map2.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
          }
      });

       
      
      } 
    }).addTo(map2);
  map2.fitBounds(selectedArea2.getBounds());
}




